# Define missing symbols in Clojure

Tags: macros, clojure, symbols

I am trying to write a macro that, given a form, defines all missing symbols as themselve.

By now I have the following:

```
(def ^:private missing-symbol-pattern #"Unable to resolve symbol: (.+) in this context")

(cl/defn ^:private missing-symbol [s]
  (cl/when-let [[_ sym] (cl/re-find missing-symbol-pattern s)] sym))

(cl/defmacro try-eval [expr]
               `(try (do (cl/println '~expr) (cl/eval '~expr)) 
                 (catch Exception e#
                   (cl/if-let [sym# (do (cl/println (.getMessage e#)) (missing-symbol (.getMessage e#)))]
                              (cl/eval `(do 
                                          (def ~(cl/symbol sym#) '~(cl/symbol sym#))
                                          (cl/println ~sym#)
                                          (try-eval ~'~expr)))
                              (cl/eval `(throw ~e#))))))
```

(`cl` here is an alias for `clojure.core`)
I know that there can be problems with side-effects, but this is not important here (although a solution without side-effect problems would be better)

If there is more than one missing (unresolvable) symbol, I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't embed object in code, maybe print-dup not defined: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Symbol cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IDeref, compiling:(shen/primitives.clj:517)
```

Has anyone an idea on what to change? Is there some "ready made" solution?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using try/catch to find symbols that won't resolve, maybe you could do something using `&env` symbol available inside of `defmacro`. The keys of `&env` are the locally defined symbols.

([Article about &env and &form.](http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/02/clojure-and.html))

Using a combination of `resolve` and `(keys &env)` you can isolate the symbols that aren't defined, then you can choose to def the ones that are `(not (or (resolve sym) (contains? &env sym))`

We do something akin to this in the [Midje source code](https://github.com/marick/Midje/blob/754d61bfb4cd89277b3f08cc926d7b311a53179c/src/midje/ideas/tabular.clj#L34), to determine which symbols in a tabular test are already defined and which ones aren't:

[Note: in the below code `locals` is in fact `(keys &env)`]

```
(defn- headings-rows+values [table locals]
  (letfn [(table-variable? [s]
            (and (symbol? s)
              (not (metaconstant-symbol? s))
              (not (resolve s))
              (not (contains? locals s))))]
    (split-with table-variable? (remove-pipes+where table))))
```

Comment: `((set (keys &env)) sym)` is just a slow way to write `(contains? &env sym)`, right? Still, cool solution - seems like it should be obvious but I didn't think of it, so I guess not!

Comment: yeah, let me edit my solution, with `contains?`, that was just an oversight.

Comment: @missingfaktor darn I should have linked to a specific revision. It looks like the code moved.  Ok, fixed the link. Thx.